# Handle Links in Restful Webservice Client

Tags: rest, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I'm implementing a client to a restful webservice, that returns results in a linked-list kind of way, where each element, besides the actual contents has a URI pointing to the next part of the result.

```
@XmlRootElement()
public class PagedResult<T> {
    private List<T> values;
    private URI next;
}
```

Using jax-rs(jersey) with jax-b there is plenty of documentation on how to create these links on the server side, but I'm not sure whats the preferred way to handle this on the client. I could obviously parse the URI and do the request myself, but that seems wrong.

Is there a simple way to get a getNext() method (returning PagedResult, not URI)?